# How to bind CustomDateEditor to all Date fields in Springframework?

Tags: java, spring

I am having a dataBind which is having few attributes alongwith a list of bean and one of the attribute of the bean is of type Date. Now i would like to add the customDateEditor to this date field.
My Databind goes like this:

```
    public class myDataBind{
       /* 
    some attributes here
    */

List myList = new ArrayList();  // List of myBean

/*
  accessor and mutators here
*/
    }
```

---

```
public class myBean{
       /* 
    some attributes here
    */

  private Date fromDate = null;
  private Date toDate = null;

/*
  accessor and mutators here
*/

}
```

---

and in my  Controller i am having

```
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {       
    super.initBinder(request, binder);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"){{ setLenient(false);}},false)); // Date.class is java.sql.Date.class    
}
```

---

But still i am getting the error
*Field error in object 'command' on field 'myList[0].fromDate': rejected value [2009-05-27]; codes [typeMismatch.command.myList[0].fromDate,typeMismatch.command.myList.fromDate,typeMismatch.myList[0].fromDate,typeMismatch.myList.fromDate,typeMismatch.fromDate,typeMismatch.java.sql.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [command.myList[0].fromDate,myList[0].fromDate]; arguments []; default message [myList[0].fromDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.sql.Date] for property 'myList[0].fromDate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.sql.Date] for property 'fromDate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]***

Please let me know, which step i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but: do you need to call super.initBinder(request, binder)?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a while back since I used Spring's validation framework. By looking at your code and the details you provided I didn't find any discrepancies. The only difference I noted when looking at my code was that I first created the CustomDateEditor, registered it with the binder and then called the super.initBinder.

Just for curiosity, did you try something like this

```
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {               
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"){{ setLenient(false);}},false));
        super.initBinder(request, binder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the error it mentions 'java.sql.Date' - in both your custom property editory and you bean class is the Date class referred to java.sql.Date or java.util.Date?

I.e. have you imported the intended Date class in all places?

Answer (score 0):

`CustomDateEditor` can only be used for `java.util.Date` !

This is documented in the class's [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomDateEditor.html).